# How can I set a value using paste0?

Tags: r, for-loop, paste

I try to create a set of values with a for loop using paste0 but get an error:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  paste0('value_',i) <- paste0('test',i)
}

Fehler in paste0("value_", i) <- i : 
  Ziel der Zuweisung expandiert zu keinem Sprachobjekt
```

I want it like this but with a for loop:

```
value_1 <- paste0('test',1)
value_2 <- paste0('test',2)
value_3 <- paste0('test',3)

> value_1
[1] "test1"
> value_2
[1] "test2"
> value_3
[1] "test3"
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use vectors or lists. Consider variable names as *static*, not modifiable. In your case, the solution doesn’t even need a loop: `value = paste0('test', 1 : 3)`.

Comment: that's not what I need as I want value_1 value_2 etc. What works is "assign" (cp. my own answer)

Comment: OK, then you need to explain *why* (you think) you need this. As it stands, this is a fundamental anti-pattern: code shouldn’t be written this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can try createing a names list, and then write the list's elements to the global environment

```
L <- lapply( 1:3, function(x) paste0( "test", x ) )
names(L) <- paste0( "value_", 1:3 )
list2env( L, envir = .GlobalEnv )
```

Comment: Please don’t recommend anti-patterns without a detailed explanation of why this is a bad idea in general, and mentioning better solutions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I will *most certainly* not eplain my answer any more than is needed (or requested) by TS. *He* is asking the question, he can deal with the answers himself. Kudo's for raising the flag about anti-patterns, but downvoting answers just because they *could* imply bad programming (you do **not** know the XY of this question yourself) is, at the very least, not at all friendly towards the people that took the time to provide an answer to the question 'as-is'. If you really want to help, provide an answer yourself, or vote to close the question.

Comment: I provided an answer, in a comment. And since Stack Overflow is an *educational resource* I maintain that it is *paramount* to explain anti-patterns, rather than offering them up unquestioningly. Your answer is *not* helping OP, it’s doing them a disservice. Providing bad answers is worse than providing none at all.

Answer (score -1):

"assign" works:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0('value_',i),paste0('test',i))
}
```

Somebody posted this before but deleted it - thanks anyway!

Comment: *This is not a good solution!* And that’s why the other answer was deleted. *Why* do you think you need individual variables rather than a vector? What you seem to have here is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), i.e. you’re looking for a solution to the wrong problem, and if you provided more relevant information we could help you solve the *actual* problem better, rather than via discouraged workarounds.